# FHIR API with SNOMED CT showing error 'The latest version of the requested CodeSystem (http://snomed.info/sct) was not found.'

Tags: hl7-fhir, snomed-ct

I am getting the below error while working with FHIR API and  SNOMED CT showing error 'The latest version of the requested Code System (http://snomed.info/sct) was not found.')

{
"resource Type": "Operation Outcome",
"issue": [
{
"severity": "error",
"code": "not-found",
"diagnostics": "The requested Code System (http://snomed.info/sct/83821000000107/version/20221123) was not found."
}
]
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL47j.png)

Comment: You could start by providing enough information to describe what you're submitting to the server to create this response, and what server you're submitting this to

Comment: Agree with Grahame that further information is needed to fully answer this.  It seems that you are looking for a very recent version of the UK edition - which the server presumably doesn't have loaded at this point.  Is this message about having not found the "latest version" of the code system coming from Ontoserver?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I am trying to create a sample valueset to my local snowstorm instance. The request is as below.


{
 "resourceType": "ValueSet",
  "url": "http://localhost:8081/fhir/ValueSet/procedure ",
  "name":"procedure",
  "compose": {
  "include": [
    {
      "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
      "filter": [
        {
          "property": "constraint",
          "op": "=",
          "value": "<< 30506011000036107 |Australian product|: 700000101000036108 |hasTP| = 17311000168105 |Panadol|"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
}

Comment: I have attached the image which shows the request and response.hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If a CodeSystem is missing from your [Snowstorm FHIR Terminology Server](https://github.com/IHTSDO/snowstorm) it can be added by following the documentation: [Loading & updating SNOMED CT with local Extensions or Editions](https://github.com/IHTSDO/snowstorm/blob/9.2.0/docs/updating-snomed-and-extensions.md).

The CodeSystems that have been loaded can be listed in the standard way using the /fhir/CodeSystem endpoint.

The [SNOMED URI standard](http://snomed.org/uri) is used to refer to SNOMED CodeSystems. The latest version of a CodeSystem can be selected by omitting the `/version/xxx` part of the URI, for example `http://snomed.info/sct/83821000000107`.

Please note that each version of a SNOMED CT edition or extension are listed as separate items in the FHIR API whereas in the Snowstorm native API codesystems and versions are listed separately.